# Transitions not working on dynamically added elements in jQuery Mobile 1.4.0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using .append() to create a set of buttons with dynamically created classes and ids(so they are the right colour) with a for loop. The classes and ids are in a JSON item[] array.

```
$("#display").append('<div class="ui-block-a"><a href="#" data-transition="flip" id="'+item[i].CssId+'" class="'+items[i].CssClass+' ui-btn ui-corner-all">'+item[i].Name+'</a></div>');
```

The transitions don't work.

If I just create a static button as a test, the transitions do work.

Why is this?

I've tried using both of these:

```
$("#display").trigger('updatelayout'); 
$("#display").trigger('create');
```

based on other StackOverflow answers but it doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$("#display").enhanceWithin();`
and add to make it act like a button `data-role="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Just worked this out.

It's because there was no reference in the a href="#" tag as I was using function to change the window location.

Comment: I think I may be having this problem. Could you elaborate on this a bit please?